# How to design a regular expression that can safely capture various types of numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

In the text corpus I'm working on, there are various types of numbers to be captured. Specifically, the types of numbers including:

- 10 000
- 10,000
- -3.33 × 10-3
- 8.× 104 (this is actually 8.×10**4, no whitespace between 8. and ×)
- 5×104 (this is actually 5×10**4)
- 12.123
- 12

How can I construct a regular expression that can safely capture all the seven types of numbers? I started from the regular expression that captures floating point numbers `[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.?)[0-9]+`, and came up with a solution `[+-]?(?:[0-9]*[\.\,\s\×])?\s?[0-9]+\-?[0-9]?`. However, this cannot cover all the seven possibilities, and it seems the resulting solution will be tedious if I simply make more modifications on this.

Is there an elegent solution?

### **UPDATE**

Based on EatenbyaGuru's advice, I came up with three regular expressions for covering the seven possibilities

```
digit_part0 = r"[+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\s?(?:×\s?10-?[0-9])?"
digit_part1 = r"[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*\s?(?:×\s?10-?[0-9])?"
digit_part2 = r"[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*[\s,][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?"
```

in which `digit_prat0` is for covering case #3, 4 and 6; `digit_part1` is for covering case # 5 and 7; `digit_part2` is for covering case # 1, 2. At this point, there can be overlapping cases between `digit_part0` and `digit_part1`.

### **UPDATE 2**

Now I construct a single regular expression that can hopefully capture all the possibilities

`[+-]?(?:[1-9][0-9]+[\s,])?(?:[0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+\s?(?:×\s?10-?[0-9])?`

Comment: couldn't you just write 7 patterns and use alternation?

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue maybe not, if I just write 7 patterns and match, I doubt there will be some overlapping results.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky Perhaps if you write out the overlapping cases, and search using the cases that don't overlap with others first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no safe generic way to do this. You can only work from your input data and cover the cases that are in there, which always means that you need to adapt and make compromises.

The following regex targets the numbers defined in your sample:

```
-?\d[\d .,]*\b
```

and matches like this:

- 10 000 *(→ `10 000`)*
- 10,000 *(→ `10,000`)*
- -3.33 × 10-3 *(→ `-3.33`, `10`, `-3`)*
- 8.× 104 *(→ `8`, `104`)*
- 5×104 *(→ `5`, `104`)*
- 12.123 *(→ `12.123`)*
- 12 *(→ `12`)*

If you want to match *expressions*, you could say `X(?:YX)*`, where `X` is the regex for numbers, and `Y` the regex for allowed operators, including surrounding fluff (e.g. whitespace).

So if we say the allowed operators should be `\.? *(?:×|-) *` for now (the `\.` is only in there to cover your `8.× 104` case), you would end up with:

```
-?\d[\d .,]*\b(?:\.? *(?:×|-) *-?\d[\d .,]*\b)*
│            |   |            ||            |
└─────X──────┘(?:└─────Y──────┘└─────X──────┘)*
```

which matches like this:

- 10 000 *(→ `10 000`)*
- 10,000 *(→ `10,000`)*
- -3.33 × 10-3 *(→ `-3.33 × 10-3`)*
- 8.× 104 *(→ `8.× 104`)*
- 5×104 *(→ `5×104`)*
- 12.123 *(→ `12.123`)*
- 12 *(→ `12`)*

I'm sure you will find cases where this is not specific enough, or not generic enough. Update the "number" and "operator" components as needed.

For example, `-?\d[\d .,]*\b` might be too simplistic. There is nothing that stops it from matching things like `1,,,,,0` or `10000.0,0.0,0`. If things like this won't occur in your input data, it's probably fine as is. If you need to make it smarter so it recognizes legal digit grouping or discards nonsensical delimiter combinations, make it smarter. It all depends.